# redirect user to homepage if page not found react router, in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

This is my main `App` component:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <Root />,
    children: [
      { path: "/", element: <Users /> },
      { path: "/users", element: <Users /> },
      { path: "/places", element: <Places /> },
    ],
  },
]);

function App() {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}

export default App;
```

I want to redirect user to homepage `"/"` if user enters any other route which is not in the routers. For example the user enters `"/products"` and I don't have this route defined so I want to redirect the user to homepage `"/"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can add the Homepage in children with path as "*" like below.

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <Root />,
    children: [
      { path: "/", element: <Users /> },
      { path: "/users", element: <Users /> },
      { path: "/places", element: <Places /> },
      { path: "*", element: <Homepage /> },
    ],
  },
]);

function App() {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

use * character in path, * means all routes :

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <Root />,
    children: [
      { path: "/", element: <Users /> },
      { path: "/users", element: <Users /> },
      { path: "/places", element: <Places /> },
      { path: "*", element: <Page404 /> },
    ],
  },
]);

function App() {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should render a redirect to the home `"/"` route for any path (*i.e. using a wildcard `"*"` matcher*) the app isn't specifically rendering a matching route for. Since the home `"/"` and `"/users"` routes both render the same `Users` component content you can shortcut this a bit by redirecting any "unknown" paths to `"/users"` instead. This eliminates redundant routes.

Example:

```
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  Navigate
} from 'react-router-dom';

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <Root />,
    children: [
      { path: "/users", element: <Users /> },
      { path: "/places", element: <Places /> },
      { path: "*", element: <Navigate to="/users" replace /> },
    ],
  },
]);
```